# Why is my dataframe from an excel file imported like that?

Tags: r, excel, import

I have a problem with an Excel file that I am working with in Rstudio; my data frame doesn't separate in more columns than one. I understand that it should separate itself due to the "," in the Excel.

Excel file I'm working with:
[image]

What R is giving as a result:
[image]

I tried separating it in Rstudio or importing it in different ways, but the final dataframe that it shows isn't correct.

If anyone can help me understand how to fix this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like all the data is in one column in Excel, so the behaviour is exactly what I'd expect.  Try splitting the data in Excel (Data .. Text to Columns), then saving the spreadsheet again.

Comment: I suspect you have actually (or originally) a CSV file, which you can import easily with `read.csv`.

Comment: You can try `df <- read.csv("data_file_name.csv", sep = ",")`. It seems your Excel file has CSV extension.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In most cases, SO questions should include at least some code and by adding relevant pieces from your project, you'd automagically add valuable context and details that might be easy to miss in your problem description.  For example, it's not entirely clear if it's R-to-Excel or Excel-to-R issue. Or if "Excel files" in question are XLSX files(native Excel format), CSV files (tabular text data) or something else, those all might be listed with some variation of an Excel icon in Explorer, and it can be somewhat confusing when file extensions are also hidden (default). [cont]

Comment: [cont] But if you'd include enough R code, we'd know if you are struggling with data import,  export or both, what kind of libraries you are using and what are the actual file types you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `read_excel()` from the `readxl` package to read the Excel file, to my knowledge, it does not have a delimiter option.

The simplest way to make it work is to use your Excel program to convert "Text to Columns" while specifying the delimiter is a comma (e.g., if you are using Excel on a MacOS, you would go to `Data` > `Text to Columns...`, select `Delimited` and click `Next`, specify `Comma` as your delimiter, and click `Finish`. Save the file and use `read_excel()` to import the newly saved file in R.

```r
library(readxl)
R_P1 <- read_excel("R_P1_new.xlsx")
                                                                                               
#   Edad Genero Hijos Fumador Region    Prima_del_seguro
#  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                <dbl>
#1    19 female     0 yes     southwest           16885.
#2    18 male       1 no      southeast            1726.
```

**Long-winded alternative:**
If you don't convert Text to Columns on the Excel file first, there are longer ways to correct your data frame solely in R. Here is an example.

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

R_P1 <- read_excel("R_P1_old.xlsx", col_names = FALSE) %>% 
    separate_wider_delim(1, ",", names_sep = "_") %>% 
    mutate_all(str_remove_all, "\"") %>% 
    `colnames<-`(.[1,]) %>% 
    .[-1,] %>% 
    mutate_all(type.convert, as.is = TRUE)

#   Edad Genero Hijos Fumador Region    Prima_del_seguro
#  <int> <chr>  <int> <chr>   <chr>                <dbl>
#1    19 female     0 yes     southwest           16885.
#2    18 male       1 no      southeast            1726.
```

**Explanation of the long-winded method:**
`read_excel("R_P1_old.xlsx", col_names = FALSE)` – imports the original one-column Excel file format and does not read the first row as column names (instead, column names become row 1).

`separate_wider_delim(1, ",", names_sep = "_")` – separates the first column (`1`) by the comma delimiter (`","`) into multiple columns, and gives column names an arbitrary separator (`names_sep = "_"`), which will be overwritten from one of the following steps.

`mutate_all(str_remove_all, "\"")` – the OP's strings have `\"` in them, so this function removes all `\"` from the data frame.

`` `colnames<-`(.[1,]) `` – column names get new names from row 1 values, which are the true column names.

`.[-1,]` – remove row 1 because it only holds the column names

`mutate_all(type.convert, as.is = TRUE)` – converts all data to their appropriate types; `as.is = TRUE` stores strings as *characters* instead of *factors*.

Disclaimer: This extended code works specifically for the OP's type of file format. It may not work with everybody's (e.g., it won't work if some strings contain commas within them). Additional custom functions may be needed to properly handle other data information.